# Make a services.msc Shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts

I have a wireless printer and for whatever reason, when I print it sends it to the printer queue but the printer itself just continues to zzZZzzz. Anyways, I have found that when I do RUN > services > Printer Spooler > Restart , the printer will then see and print whatever is in the printing queue.

I want to make a shortcut (or batch script) to do that ( RUN > services > Printer Spooler > Restart ). Is it possible, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up notepad and paste the following

> @echo off
>
> echo RESTARTING THE PRINT SPOOLER SERVICES
>
> net stop "print spooler"
>
> net start "print spooler"
>
> echo FINISHED RESTARTING PRINT SPOOLER

(Feel free to delete the first two and the last line!)

Save this anywhere as a .cmd or .bat file* (basically, call it restart printer.cmd)

If you have UAC on, you will need to right click and do "Run as administrator", if you do not have UAC on, you can just run it.

It should restart the print spooler service.

If it does not work, make sure the extension of the file is just .bat or .cmd and not .bat.txt or .cmd.txt

(it's up to you, I would personally use .cmd, but it makes no difference)

Comment: the messages are kind of redundant as the window will instantly close afterwards :P

Comment: well, I agree on the last one... but it takes nothing and looks nice!

Answer (score 2):

Use `net start <service>` and `net stop <service>` in a batch script:

```
net stop spooler
net start spooler
```

save as something like `restart.bat` on the desktop for easy access. Since it appears that you're using Vista/7, if UAC is enabled you'll need to right click the batch script and run as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

In your batch file run the following commands

```
net stop "Print Spooler"
net start "Print Spooler"
```